# Issue with aligning using vh

Tags: html, css

I'm actually trying to create a navigation bar.

However I want it to be about 7vh and I want the font to adjust with this.
The problem is that the small hover effect border won't be aligned perfectly all the time (Display in fullscreen).

If anyone knows how to fix this it would be very much appreciated.

```css
* {
  font-family: Futura;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
  background: #2b2b2a;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  height: 7vh;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

/* NOTE: Classes */

/* NOTE: Text elements */

.nav-link {
  font-size: 4vh;
  margin: 0px 1%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1vh;
  top: 1vh;
}

.column-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 0.3vh;
}

.column-text {
  text-align: left;
}

#premiere {
  font-size: 3vh;
  float: right;
  transform: translate(-5%, -110%);
}

/* NOTE: Box elements */

.home-column-warper {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 2vh 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid white;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* NOTE: Other */

.logo-image {
  height: 5.5vh;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0.7vh;
  margin-left: 0.7vh;
  transform: translate(0%, -110%)
}

.vline {
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: solid 3px LightBlue;
  padding-bottom: 0.4vh;
}

::selection {
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
}

/* NOTE: IDs */

#nav-warper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6vh;
}

/* NOTE: Hover */

.nav-link:hover {
  color: wheat;
  border-bottom: solid 3px LightBlue;
  padding-bottom: 0.4vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bac 2018</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./data/CSS/styling.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div id="nav-warper">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link selected">Accueil</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./data/Pages/plans.html" class="nav-link">Plans</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./data/Pages/cours.html" class="nav-link">Cours</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./data/Pages/plus.html" class="nav-link">Plus</a>
      </div>
      <img src="./data/Media/logo.png" alt="Logo du site" class="logo-image">
      <span id="premiere">Première Littéraire</span>
    </nav><br><br><br>
    <div class="home-column-warper">
      <div class="column">
        <p class="column-title">PLANS</p>
        <span>Cette section regroupe tout les plans des oeuvres ou extraits vu en lecture analytique en français et littérature. Elle comporte quelques documents vu en lecture cursive ainsi que des résumés des oeuvres vu en classe. Pour obtennir la définition d'un mot passer le curseur dessus, les mots dotés d'une définition sont soulignés. Il est possible que certaines fiches contiennent des erreurs, idem pour les résumés d'oeuvres ou de documents en lecture cursive. Donc si vous voyez une erreur ou une information qui manque, envoyez moi un mail : miloertas@gmail.com, ça évitera que tout le monde apprennent un truc faux...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p class="column-title">COURS</p>
        <span>Cette section regroupe les principaux cours de l'année. Tout ce qui est notions, objets d'études ou en relation avec l'oral se retrouve dans cette section. Informations sur objets d'études et cours théorique également dedans</span>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p class="column-title">PLUS</p>
        <span>Cette section regroupe toutes les notifications d'erreurs ou les documents inclassables. Bientôt cette section contiendra les documents scan des textes pour le bac oral.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p class="column-title">MODIFICATIONS</p>
        <span>Cette section regroupe toutes les modifications oppérés sur le site (Comprend la correction de bugs l'ajout de fonctionnalités et la correction d'erreur dans les fiches).<br>- Ajout de la section PLUS.<br>- Correction FICHE, Dom Juan v1 : "C'est une dimension tragique et non une tragédie".</span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the of the dis-align on the element hover is most likely beacause it doesnt exist before the hover takes place so add this Line:

```
border-bottom: solid 3px transparent;
```

To the:

```
.nav-link
```

Should probably Solve it :)

Comment: I talked with the duck and realized what my mistake was.

Comment: Technically I was adding relative values (vh, %) with fixed (px, em) and at some point it would create that effect.

Comment: I'll confirm yours dw you still tried to help me out